# Should we merge the tags [definition] and [terminology]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

We currently have the tags [definition](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) and [terminology](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) which seem to be used with the same purpose. The [terminology] tag is one of our more popular tags with 60 questions, and it also has some rudimentary [usage guidance](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/terminology/info). On the other hand, there are only four questions tagged [definition]:

- [What makes a song an anthem?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3509/3955)
- [Tour not supporting a new album](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4182/3955)
- [Recognising genre and sub-genre](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4812/3955)
- [Name for commercial song which becomes accepted as folk song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5682/3955)

The tag [definition] also lacks any usage guidance.

Considering its low usage, lack of usage guidance, and the nature of the questions with that tag, I suggest that we merge [definition] into [terminology], keeping the latter as the master tag. Alternatively—if merging is too much effort—we can retag the questions tagged [definition] so that we can burninate the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the questions tagged [definition](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) have been retagged to [terminology](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology). The [definition](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tag has been burninated.